# HQL new list creation and order by count

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm doing a HQL query as follows, and try to order the list by count column:

```
select new Persons(count(*) as cnt, p.id, p.name, p.city) group by p.city order by cnt
```

How ever Hibernate is giving me following error:

```
Unknown column 'cnt' in 'order clause'
```

Is there a way to include the city count to person object and get a list that is also ordered by count, or do I have to do it in some other way?

I'm using MySQL as database backend.

Cheers,

OsQu

Comment: By the way, your select is wrong. In the `group by` you have to include all selected columns which are not aggregate functions. You either do `group by p.id, p.name, p.city` or you only select `new Persons(count(*) as cnt, p.city)`. The way you are doing might work with MySQL (producing arbitrary values for id and name), but it does not work with Oracle.

Comment: I'm using MySQL as a backend. Sorry for inconvience, updating the question. Btw, what's the point of grouping if you're going to group by all the columns?

Comment: Yep. Grouping by the id does not make sense, because count(*) would be 1 all the time. No, the point is, when you use 'group by', then in correct SQL you only can select either aggregate columns or columns mentioned in the group by clause. For example, if you select p.id and you group by p.city, which id of the many rows with the same city the select shall return? MySQL is quite sloppy here, but Oracle throws an error. If you only need dummy values to fulfill the  needs of the Persons constructor, then do `select new Persons(count(*) cnt, 0 id, 'dummy' name, p.city) group by p.city`

Comment: Btw., for your original question, try `order by Persons.cnt`

Comment: Johanna that really makes sense! Thanks a lot, I'm one step closer to understand the group by-clause correctly. It has giving me problems to understand lately.. I'll try the Persons.cnt next time I'm at the project.

Comment: Ah, you can give count(*) to order by clause! Stupid me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it was something so simple that adding count(*) to order by clause. So working solution:

```
select new Persons(count(*) as cnt, p.id, p.name, p.city) group by p.city order by count(*);
```